# Converting while loop to recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

Hi I'm trying to convert this java while loop code into recursion. I have tried converting it into recursion but I keep getting an error. the while loop works fine is just when I convert it into recursion is when I get an error. Any help on how to convert it into recursion will be appreciated, Thank you.

```
public static boolean hasCycle( Node head) {
    Node slow = head;
    Node fast = head; 
    boolean loop = false; 
    while (slow != null && fast != null && fast.getNext() != null) {
        slow = slow.getNext();
        fast = fast.getNext().getNext();

        if(slow == fast) {
            loop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return loop;

}
```

//recursion code

```
    Node slow = head;
    Node fast = head; 
    boolean loop = false; 

    if(slow == fast) {
        return true;
    }else if(slow != fast) {
        if(slow.getNext() != null) {
            return hasCycle(slow.getNext());
        }
        return false;
    }else {
        if(fast.getNext() != null) {
            return hasCycle(fast.getNext());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: keeps saying an error at the line where I call my recursive function

Comment: You have to tell us what the error is for us to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Also, this will always be true: ` if(slow == fast) ` because in the lines above it you set both `slow = head` and `fast = head`.

Comment: "But I get an error" is not helpful. Tell us where the error is (put a comment on that line), and copy the *exact text* of the error. Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to only be checking for immediate loops in your first iterative version. (You are not checking if you have a larger loop A -> B -> C -> A. You are only checking for loops like A -> B -> A). I assume that what you presented is correct and what you want, albeit strange. (If you have a larger loop it will go on infinitely).

The proper and simpler way to do what you presented recursively is:

```
public boolean hasImmediateCycle(Node node) {
   if (node == null || node.getNext() == null) {
      return false;
   } else if (node == node.getNext().getNext()) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return hasImmediateCycle(node.getNext());
   }
}
```

If you wanted to make it check for all possible loops you would need to do it slightly differently:

```
private boolean hasCycle(Node node, Set<Node> seen) {
   if (node == null) {
      return false;
   } else if (seen.contains(node)) {
      return true;
   } else {
      seen.add(node);   
      return hasCycle(node.getNext(), seen);
   }
}

public boolean hasCycle(Node node) {
  return hasCycle(node, new HashSet<Node>());
}
```

This will check all the `seen` nodes in case they appear again in the `next` reference. This actually uses the `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` of your `Node` so it is important they are implemented consistently with each other.